# How to add a fuction to Repair - update a cell in database table in specific id in model php file

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I make a remake of an extension so I stuck in the last work that I must to do.
I created a twig for admin which displays a list that take data from a table in the database. In each row of the list I created a button that I want to fix specific cell of the table. So each line has its own id.

See the image from page list:

[image]

I made the controller file but I stuck in model file that must do the rest work.

In the following code I have to change something so that by pressing the repair button it reads the specific id.

```
public function repairSaveCarts($link_id=" ") {
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "save_cart WHERE link_id = '" . (int)$link_id . "'");

        $db_id = $this->db->getLastId();
            $end_url = base64_encode(serialize($db_id));
            $url = $this->config->get('config_url').$end_url;
            
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "save_cart SET shorturl = '" . $this->db->escape($url) . "' WHERE link_id = '" . (int)$db_id . "'");
    }
```

I thing that the change must be done in `$db_id = $this->db->getLastId();` line but I'm not sure.
Someone that can help please.

Comment: Hello Geodas, `$this->db->getLastId();` will usually return the primary key value of a row after inserting a new row. It's not really clear what you're trying to fix here, looking at the code, it's querying the cart table, then updating the cart table after modifying (what should be) the result. Can you explain what `repairSaveCarts()` is supposed to do?

Comment: So far I had 3 values in the database table. To these I added 2 more, one with date added and the second with shorturl. I made the necessary changes for frontend & work fine. But for the old data that exists in the table I had to find a way to update these 2 cells.
What I want the update button to do when I press it is to read the id of specific line and create a link to update the shorturl cell in same line with the base64_encode(serialize().
In frontend the base64_encode(serialize(db_id) ends with setOutput(json_encode($json)); and give me a link such us http://*shopname*/aToyOw==.

Comment: So you want to `base64_encode(serialize($link_id))`, append that encoded string to the website URL and update the `oc_save_cart` table with that full URL? Is `$link_id` the same ID you want to read? If not, what is the column name that contains the id value? `save_cart_id`?

Comment: The link_id is the Id value in my table. The `base64_encode(serialize())` must read from database the existing id value and give me as example for number id (2) take  aToyOw== . If you decode this by using [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/)  you take as result `i:2;`  the number 2 is the id value in my table (link_id).

Comment: If `link_id` is the primary key value and, when calling the function, you know the value, why do we need this line `$db_id = $this->db->getLastId();`? Do you expect it to return a value that is different to `link_id`? Can you post the table schema for the `save_cart` table?

Comment: Let's make things a little simpler because we started to get confused.Τhe schema for the save_cart table is:`'link_id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'options'  mediumtext NOT NULL,'shorturl' varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,'coupon' varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,'date_added' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,PRIMARY KEY ('link_id')) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
I never said that the code is correct.The `base64_encode(serialize())` code must read `link_id` & update only the `shorturl` from table. I think that now I'm clear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally i make it. I replace this:

```
public function repairSaveCarts($link_id, $base) {
    $end_url = base64_encode(serialize($link_id));
    $url = $base.$end_url;
        
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "save_cart SET shorturl = '" . $this->db->escape($url) . "' WHERE link_id = '" . (int)$link_id . "'");
}
```

with this on model file:

```
public function repairSaveCarts($link_id) {
    $end_url = base64_encode(serialize((int)$link_id));
    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    $url = HTTPS_CATALOG . $end_url;
    } else {
    $url = HTTP_CATALOG . $end_url;
    }
        
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "save_cart SET shorturl = '" . $this->db->escape($url) . "', date_added = NOW() WHERE link_id = '" . (int)$link_id . "'");
}
```

Thank you Daniel for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I make it work. I had a small syntax error in `request->get | post` at controller and for this reason the model didn't get the correct id from button.

```
public function repairSaveCarts($link_id) {
        
        $end_url = base64_encode(serialize((int)$link_id));
        
        $url = $this->config->get('config_url').$end_url;
        
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "save_cart SET shorturl = '" . $this->db->escape($url) . "', date_added = NOW() WHERE link_id = '" . (int)$link_id . "'");
        
    
        
        return $query->row;
    }
```

One thing I notice with `serialize` is that when the model got the id from the controller it received it as a `spring` value and not as an `int` value. The result was to give as example for

`id 10 ---> serialize value=  s:2:"10";`

To fix this i add in model the `(int)` value after `serialize` and now give me the correct results

`id 10 ---> serialize value=  i:10;`.

The only problem now is that when the module save to database from frond-end page give me the full URL site:

`https://www.example.com/aToxMDs=`

but when in admin side the functionRepair save to database give me only:

`aToxMDs=`

The line
`$url = $this->config->get('config_url').$end_url;`
seems that doesn't work.

What i must edit to add the store url before the `$end_url`???

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of the function for your model class:

```
public function repairSaveCarts($link_id, $base) {
    $end_url = base64_encode(serialize($link_id));
    $url = $base.$end_url;
        
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "save_cart SET shorturl = '" . $this->db->escape($url) . "' WHERE link_id = '" . (int)$link_id . "'");
}
```

You should also cater for HTTPS not just HTTP, so add the following to the controller to get the site Url and pass that value to the 'repair' function. This should be done just before the existing call to the model function:

```
// check if the request was made over HTTPS or not
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    $server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
} else {
    $server = $this->config->get('config_url');
}

$this->whateveryourmodelnameis->repairSaveCarts($link_id, $server);
```

Comment: I make the change to propose in model. Without make any change to controller i take `ArrayaTo0ODs=`. The word `Array` from `$base` and the `aTo0ODs=` comes from `$end_url`.What i must set in controller for `$base`. I didn't see the `$base` on the controller.You have `$server` in the HTTPS check.The line that post in controller is this:`$this->model_extension_savecart->repairSaveCarts($this->request->get['link_id'], $this->request->post);`. How to change the post request to send the `$base` to model.Where this line must go:`$this->model_extension_savecart->repairSaveCarts($link_id, $server);`.

Comment: I think you need to spend some time learning how OpenCart's MVC framework works. That will take care of most of your additional questions. Here's a tutorial that will help you: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-opencart-understanding-mvc--cms-21627